# If $A$ is an invertible $n \times n$ matrix, then for all natural $m$ no row of $A^m$ vanishes

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I want to prove that as $A$ is invertible, any power of $A$ will not have any rows completely vanish. I am not sure what properties I can use to prove this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If row $m$ vanishes, right multiplication by $e_m^T$ yields $0$ where $e_m$ is basis vector $m$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$det (A) \neq 0$ implies $ det(A^m) \neq 0$ therefore all rows of $A^m$ are linearly independent , so none of them can be a zero vector.

Comment: ah really, is there a name for the theorem regarding the non-zero determinant of A implying all of the powers of A also have non-zero determinant?

Comment: $det (AB) = det (A) det(B)$ ,  Are you familiar with this relation ?

Comment: Ah yes of course, just found it in my notes actually, thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way, I think, is to observe that for all $  n $, $A ^n $ is invertible. This means that its columns are linearly independent so they won't vanish.

Answer (score 1):

The concepts of linear independence and determinants are not necessary to answer this question. You only need: the definition of invertible, the fact that if $A$ is invertible then $A^m$ is invertible, and the definition of matrix multiplication.

**Fact 1:** If a square matrix has a row of zeros, then it is not invertible.

You can prove this directly from the definition of invertible matrix and the definition of matrix multiplication. In fact, this should be among one of the first things mentioned in any textbook after defining matrix multiplication and/or invertibility.

**Contrapositive of fact 1:** If a square matrix is invertible, then it does not have a row of zeros.

**Fact 2:** If a square matrix $A$ is invertible, then $A^m$ is invertible.

Combine the contrapositive of fact 1 and fact 2.